# How do I explode() these variables?

Tags: php

I have 3 Variables.

```
$Full Name = 'John Smith'
$Address = '4732 E Cherry St'
$Type = array('Residential','Commercial');
```

I then need to check the `$Type` to give me the END of my `$JobName` so I will do the following...

```
if ($type == 'Residential') { $JobType = 'R'; }
else if ($type == 'Commercial') { $JobType = 'C'; }
```

I need to get the output of `$JobName = 'Smith-4732-R'`

So how do I strip the Last name from the `$FullName` var, and only the address # from the `$Address` to give me **Smith-4732-R**?

Revised Code...

```
$FullName = 'John Smith';
$Address = '4732 E Cherry St';
$Type = 'Residential';

$parts = explode(" ", $FullName);
$ClientLastName = array_pop($parts);

$parts = explode(" ", $Address);
$AddressSnip = print_r(array_slice($parts,0,1));

if ($Type == 'Residential') { $JobType = 'R'; }
else if ($Type == 'Commercial') { $JobType = 'C'; }


echo $ClientLastName . '-' . $AddressSnip  . '-' . $JobType;
```

When I execute the above, I get the following. `Array ( [0] = 4732 ) Smith-1-R`

Comment: if you always have spaces and the name and address are always in the same format you can `explode` with the empty space as the delimiter

Comment: To answer this, you will have to know and tell us all the rules for how name and address can be formatted.

Comment: use `explode()` and `implode()` if the data is stored in a fixed syntax

Comment: can you not use `explode()` and just call the last and first elements, respectively?

Comment: explode() is it! I couldnt remember it. However can someone show me a quick example of how I would explode these variables?

Comment: Look up the documentation for `explode()`. There are examples.

Comment: Name format will always be First & Lastname (John Smith), address will always be a series of digits first then a space follolwed by direction, etc. (4732) @mseifert

Comment: I have Updated my Question. I am having a difficulty wrapping this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$FullName = explode(" ",$FullName);
$lastName = $FullName[sizeof($FullName)-1];

$Address = explode(" ",$Address);
$Address = $Address[0];

echo $lastName . '-' . $Address  . '-' . $JobType;
```

It should be working. Hope it helps =)

Comment: Winner Winner, Chicken Dinner!

Answer (score 0):

Use [the explode() function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). 
E.g.:

```
$JobName = end(explode(" ",$FullName)).'-'.explode(" ",$Address)[0].'-'.$JobType;
```

Comment: Getting an erro ' unexpected '[' at the `[0]`